# Yii2- how open generated module in browser (what url)

Tags: php, yii2

I have created module "Admin" in gii generator in Yii2 (my module is named "Admin" and it could be found here **app\modules\admin\Admin.php**)
But how can I open this module in my browser. What url I should use.

Url https://regexp/web/index.php?r=admin returns 404

Answer (score 0):

To use a module in an application, simply configure the application by listing the module in the modules property of the application. The following code in the application configuration uses the forum module:

```
[
    'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Admin',
            // ... other configurations for the module ...
        ],
    ],
]
```

The modules property takes an array of module configurations. Each array key represents a module ID which uniquely identifies the module among all modules in the application, and the corresponding array value is a configuration for creating the module.

See also Yii2 [modules guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a controller named 'site' and an action named 'action', then to open them in the module 'admin', you should be able to do it with this URL: https://regexp/web/index.php?r=admin/site/action